# Kubernetes - how to access statefulset headless service from another namespace?

Tags: kubernetes

How to access headless services from another namespace?  If I try to access it by `<service>.<namespace>` then I sometimes connect to replica db `dbhost001-1`. I want to specifically connect to `dbhost001-0` master DB.

```
kubectl get pods -n test-db-dev
NAME     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
dbhost001-0   1/1     Running   0          38m
dbhost001-1   1/1     Running   0          17m
```

`headless-service.yml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: dbhost001
  labels:
    app: dbhost001-service
  namespace: test-db-dev
spec:
  selector:
    app: dbhost001   # Metadata label of the deployment pod template or pod metadata label
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - name: mysql-port    # Optional when its just only one port
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that you're using StatefulSet for the DB.

If both the StatefulSet and it's governing service name is `dbhost001`, running on `default` namespace, you can connect Pod `dbhost001-0` on address: `dbhost001-0.dbhost001.default.svc`.

Format: `<pod name>.<service name>.<namespace>.svc`